# How complex is this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am having a really hard time getting my head around algorithm complexity analysis for university. My professor is giving us simple bits of code to work out the complexity of and this is one of them:

```c
double minValue(double* pd, int& p, int N)
{
    double minV = pd[0];
    for (int i=1; i < N; i++)
        if (minV > pd[i]) {
            minV = pd[i];
            p = i;
        }
    return minV;
}
```

Can someone tell me what the complexity of this is?  My guess is `O(N²)`

Comment: if given code executes x steps for an in put of length y and nx steps for an input of length ny then it means it is O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only repetitive portion of this function is the following `for` loop:

```c
for (int i+1; i < N; i++)
```

This loop is just `O(N)`, so that is also the overall complexity of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the inputs to the function are an array, a scalar and a scalar, the array is what has an impact on your time complexity. You only go through the array once in the for loop, provided. Increasing the size of the input increases the time of the for loop linearly as it will pass through every value once. The time complexity is therefore O(N).